# how to decode get variable in php

Tags: php, decode

How to decode the `$_get` variable using PHP with out form method?

**Html code**

```
<a id="msgr"name="msgr<?php echo $d['qid'];?>"href="Chatbox.php">message</a>
```

**php code (chatbox.php)**

```
if(isset($_get["msgr"])){

    $get_id=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT MAX(qid) 
     FROM `queries` WHERE uid='".$_SESSION['id']."'"));

   $result = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM 
   `queries` where  qid='".$get_id[0]."'"));

}
```

How can I get URL  like **example.com/chatbox.php?qid=212**  ?
Please give explain and give me the solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: `$_get` does not exist. However `$_GET` does

Comment: the `$_GET` variable is populated as an associative array based on the query string content. This is either done by submitting a form or setting the URL with a query string. You are doing neither of those things here.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: @apokryfos  Yes, But there is no form just link only how can i get

Comment: @RiggsFolly give me updated code   i am new in php

Comment: `<a href='chatbox.php?msgr=<?=$d['qid']?>'>` and then check `if (isset($_GET["msgr"]))` by the way this is basic PHP things, you really need to read up on some tutorials instead of throwing badly written code here and expecting solutions.

Comment: @MunnaVMC demanding code without any effort it not how SO works.

Comment: I suggest a few minutes with the manual http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: You might also like to put some spaces into your HTML Ancjor tag `<a id="msgr" name="msgr<?php echo $d['qid'];?>" href="Chatbox.php">message</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to put it inside href attribute like:

```
<a id="msgr" href="/Chatbox.php?msgr=<?php echo $d['qid'];?>">message</a>
```

Comment: Thanks it's working but please see rest of the PHP code  in Chatbox.php   not working  example <?php echo ($result["title"]);?>